# How I can open this file on android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I can't open app folder as you see on the screenshot.
Can any one help me to solve this problem?
I use android studio.

[image]

Comment: Check on disk it looks like empty folder. Click right button and choose Synchronize 'app'

Comment: Maybe you didn't import your project properly? Try to click on the "WebView + splash screen" text and to open from there the app folder

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you may have imported something incorrectly (or at least, Android Studio didn't take it correctly).

You can try changing the view of the project by clicking on "Android" above your files:

[image]

Then choose "Project," which should bring up a different view.

If "app" is still empty, then something is wrong with the files that you imported.